# Chrome font is almost not readable

Tags: google-chrome, fonts

I've installed Chrome on Ubuntu 16.04 and there is a huge difference in fonts. In Chrome, it is almost unreadable but Firefox is ok.

**FIREFOX**
[image]

**CHROME**
[image]

Do you know how to solve it?

Comment: I'm tempted to say that the two use different font renderers. Could you please take a screenshot of the same page with *Chromium* for comparison? Thanks.

Comment: Looks like a problem with the web page's CSS, or perhaps a bug in Chrome's rendering engine not properly applying the style, and so the not highlighted items are too low contrast.

Comment: Try **High Contrast** plugin from *Google Accessibility* team: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/high-contrast/djcfdncoelnlbldjfhinnjlhdjlikmph?hl=en

Comment: Try "Chrome Font Super Enhancer" addon: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-font-super-enhance/ombebcdhklmmkcddekoplmobafpkolmd